# ReactJS component not rendering textarea with state variable

Tags: javascript, textarea, reactjs

I am facing an intriguing bug in React.

I have this component:

```
'use strict';
import SummaryStore from '../stores/SummaryStore';
import React from 'react';

export default class ChangeSummaryForm extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
       // store initialisation
       SummaryStore.register();
       
       var vRating = SummaryStore.getBookForSummaryPrint().summaryRating;
       var vStarClassName = this.getRatingClasses(vRating);
       this.state = {
            sStarClassName: vStarClassName,
            sCurrentBookToShow: SummaryStore.getBookForSummaryPrint()
       };
       
        this.thereIsASummaryToShow = this.thereIsASummaryToShow.bind(this);
    }
    
  getRatingClasses(pRating) {
      var vI, vStarClassName = [];
       for(vI = 0; vI < 4; vI++) {
          if(pRating > 0) {
             vStarClassName.push("glyphicon glyphicon-star");
             pRating--;
          } else {
             vStarClassName.push("glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty");
          }
       }
      return vStarClassName;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    SummaryStore.addChangeListener(this.thereIsASummaryToShow);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    SummaryStore.removeChangeListener(this.thereIsASummaryToShow);
  }
    
  thereIsASummaryToShow() {
      
      this.setState({sCurrentBookToShow: SummaryStore.getBookForSummaryPrint(),
                     sStarClassName: this.getRatingClasses(SummaryStore.getBookForSummaryPrint().rating)
                    });
      $("#summaryModal").modal('show');
    }
    render() {
        return (<div className="modal fade" id="summaryModal">
                  <form>
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <div className="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" ariaLabel="Close"><span ariaHidden="true">&times;                  </span>                           </button>
                <div style={{color: 'black'}}>
                    {this.state.sStarClassName.map(function(pCurrentClassName) { return (<span className={pCurrentClassName}></span>
                                                                                   );
                                                                                 })}
                        <h4 className="modal-title">Summary of {this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.title}</h4>
                </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="modal-body">

                            <div className="form-group">
                                <textarea className="form-control" rows="22" ref="summaryContent" >{this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.summary}</textarea>
                            </div>

                      </div>
                      <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Save"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
               );
    }
}
```

As you might notice, it's a [controller-view](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#listening-to-changes-with-a-controller-view) listening at a store which is registered to my AppDispatcher.

The steps above are correctly performed. i.e, when the particular action is triggerd, my component is correctly rendered with the variables  `{this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.title}` and `this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.title` up-to-date.

**The problem** comes from this part:

```
<textarea className="form-control" rows="22" ref="summaryContent" >   
  {this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.summary}
 </textarea>
```

The string is not printed in the textarea.

I tried this to debug:

```
    render() {
     var summary = "this is a summary";
     return (// .. shortened for brevity
      <textarea className="form-control" rows="22" ref="summaryContent">
       {summary}
    </textarea> ..);
    }
```

the `summary` string printed correctly inside the mutable textearea.

Note that my browser says:

> Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props instead of setting
> children on `<textarea>`.

But I will fix this later since I think it doesn't have an effect on the current problem.

**EDIT:**
I took your remarks (so far) in consideration, so I updated my code like so:

```
                <h4 className="modal-title">Summary of {this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.summary}</h4>
        </div>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">

                    <div className="form-group">
                        {this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.summary}
                        <textarea className="form-control" rows="22" ref="summaryContent" defaultValue={this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.summary}></textarea>
                    </div>
```

- I replaced `this.state.sCurrentBookToShow.title` by `.summary` to make
  sure the ladder is not empty.
- I put the summary into a `defaultValue` prop

Here is the output:
[image]

Second edit:

I uploaded a sample [app](https://github.com/MayasHaddad/react-flux-textarea-bug) that highlights the issue. I hope this would help to find a proper solution

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle we can have a look at.

Comment: @Edo My appologies, I am having difficulties to upload it because of the dependencies of the Flux architecture ... I don't know how to quickly set a jsfiddle in this situation.

Comment: Can you right click, inspect element inside the text area and report what is in there?

Comment: Please refer to this snapshot: https://www.anony.ws/image/D6Xm

Comment: As you can notice 'defaultValue' prop seems to be dismissed by React after render.

Comment: @Edo: please, take a look to https://jsfiddle.net/kr316206/1/

Comment: in the jsFiddle you provided, everything seems to work fine http://i.stack.imgur.com/8CfUk.png

Comment: In this case, I formulated the problem bad, and I lacked of understading of defaultValue property.
What I expect when I write some data in my input and hit the "submit" button is the data inside the textarea to refresh just like in the text I put beside it.
I had the answear [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4076)
Thank you for seeking to help me!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check this link from react docs: [React Textarea Value](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-textarea-value)

Basically for textArea react does not supports text enclosed within  and  you rather need to specify that as **`value`** or **`defaultValue`**.

The right way thus is

```
<textarea name="description" value="This is a description." />
```

or

```
<textarea name="description" defaultValue="This is a description." />
```

The difference with `value` and `defaultValue` is that [specifying `defaultValue` leaves the component uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values):

> With an uncontrolled component, you often want React to specify the initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify a defaultValue attribute instead of value.

...while [specifying `value` instructs React to control the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), meaning you need to update value property to make sure that change is reflected in the component:

> Since the value attribute is set on our form element, the displayed value will always be this.state.value, making the React state the source of truth.

To get a clear idea of difference between value / default value check this: [Fiddle for value Default Value Distinction](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9836/)  Console will always show new value but component will not.

Comment: You are right. I used value and update it onChange. That seems the only way.

Comment: This article, linked to from React's docs, is also useful for understanding the difference between controlled and uncontrolled components: https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is exactly what is wrong. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components):

> If you want to initialize the component with a non-empty value, you can supply a defaultValue prop.

Answer (score -4):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using controlled component, e.g.

```
state.value = this.props.value 
<textarea value={this.state.value} onchange={handler} />
```

It works fine to control the input part. However, I had another issue, I need to init/change the state.value to props.value whenever there is a re-render.

I used the lift-cycle methods and it works perfect fine.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(){
    this.setState({
        value: this.props.value
    }) }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Never do `state.value = this.props.value`. Changing the state should just be done with `this.setState(...)`, like you did in your componentWillReceiveProps.