# React-Redux is not rendering data correctly inside input/textarea box

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux

I have the example below where (1) and (2) would display the value of "Some Text" instead of `Data.preview` but (3) would show up `Data.preview` value just fine. I understand that case (1) - based on this article ([ReactJS component not rendering textarea with state variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730369/reactjs-component-not-rendering-textarea-with-state-variable)) wouldn't work for `react` but why does case (2) return "Some Text" (I also tried `value=`) instead of `Data.preview` value like case (3). I do not want it to be a placeholder so it would be editable. Thanks

```
render(){
    const { Data } = this.props
    return (
         {Data.preview} {*/this would return the value correctly*/}
         (1) <textarea className="form-control" maxLength="50" rows="3">{ Data.preview || "Some Text" }</textarea>
         (2) <textarea className="form-control" maxLength="50" rows="3" defaultValue={ Data.preview || "Some Text"}></textarea> {*/or use value = {}, either would return "Some Text" */}             
         (3) <textarea className="form-control" placeholder={Data.preview || "Some Text"} maxLength="50" rows="3"></textarea>{*/ this would return Data.preview value */}             
    )
}
```

Comment: So, you want to have a placeholder, or a standard value?

Comment: @Icepickle I would like the standard value to display so it can be edit. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS component not rendering textarea with state variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730369/reactjs-component-not-rendering-textarea-with-state-variable)

Comment: @aug that article is the reason why case (1) wouldn't work, but I'm having trouble to get case (2) (which is what I need) to work properly and display the value instead of using `placeholder`

Comment: @KendraChu ah fair enough -- retracted my close vote but still feel the auto comment of the duplicate is relevant to the question :) Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The textarea can take the `value` property for showing its current value, and then use the `onChange` handler to update that value.

In this sample I added both the one with no value yet, and the one which has a default value.

An important note would be that a value cannot be `null`; it has to be either undefined or empty.

The answer here doesn't really involve redux, but rather a component state for editing the value. I hope this helps enough to use it, applying it to your code.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class DataEntrySample extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: props.value
    };
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }
  updateData(e) {
    this.setState({ data: e.target.value });
    console.log('changed to :' + e.target.value );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea 
        value={this.state.data} 
        onChange={this.updateData} 
        placeholder={this.state.data || 'Enter your data'}>
      </textarea>
    );
  }
}

const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <div><DataEntrySample /><DataEntrySample value="Some text" /></div>, target );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you really want to do it through `defaultValue`, you have a chance to do that as well (as long as you define an `onChange` handler that updates the value somewhere).

There is rather a caveat, namely, it will not update any changes from outside of it's view, unless it can define that it has really changed, and with `defaultValue`. So the following example would work, changing the props from outside would not work.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class DataEntrySample extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: props.value
    };
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }
  updateData(e) {
    this.setState({ data: e.target.value });
    console.log('changed to :' + e.target.value );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <textarea 
        onChange={this.updateData} 
        defaultValue={this.state.data || 'Enter your data'}>
      </textarea>
    );
  }
}

class ParentEntry extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.updateProps = this.updateProps.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      value: 'initial text'
    };
  }
  updateProps( value ) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }
  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    console.log( 'render' );
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>With default value</h1>
        <DataEntrySample value={value} />
        <br />
        <button onClick={()=>this.updateProps('empty text')} type="button">
          Will set text to empty text
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const target = document.querySelector('#container');
ReactDOM.render( <ParentEntry />, target );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a bit more about controller components https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

If you then decide that you really need uncontrolled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html